# Is "type variable" the alias of "type parameter"?

Tags: haskell

Are `type variable` and `type parameter` the same thing in Haskell? E.g.:

```
ghci> :t last
last :: [a] -> a
```

`a` is both `type variable` and `type parameter`.

Comment: @luqui I strongly disagree. I think "variable-ness" and "parameter-ness"/"argument-ness" emphasize very different things.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is an abbreviated syntax for type-level terms:

```
type ::= variable
       | type type
       | constructor
       | "(" type ")"

var ::= <lowercase letter>*
constructor ::= <uppercase letter><lowercase letter>*
              | "->"
              | "[]"
```

And here's an abbreviated syntax for declarations of new data types:

```
decl     ::= "data" constructor var* "=" branches
branches ::= branch | branch "|" branches
branch   ::= constructor type*
```

It's not quite precise or complete (see the [Report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-650004.1.2) for the canonical details), but it's enough to get the discussion off the ground.

Here is a smattering of terms and what I mean when I say them:

- **type variable**: a type-level term built by the `var` production above; for example, `a`, `graph`, `foo` would be fine type variables if they appeared in a context expecting a type, but `[a]`, `Tree`, `Ord x` are not type variables and `graph` would not be a type variable in the term declaration `f graph = undefined`.
- **type parameter**: a *position* in a data declaration that points to one of the `var` arguments; for example, in `data Foo a b c = Bar a Int` I would call the `a`, `b`, and `c` to the left of `=` type parameters, but the `a` to the right would not be. To a lesser extent, "type parameter" also gets used to mean "type argument", see below, though this usage is a little bit sloppy in my opinion.
- **type argument**: a type filling in for the second part of the `type ::= type type` production above; for example, in `Foo (Maybe a)`, I would call `a` a type argument and `(Maybe a)` a type argument, but `Foo` and `Maybe` would not be. As a special case, we have `[a]` as a sort of syntactic sugar for the application `[] a`; in that case, I would also call `a` a type argument even though it is in sort of a funny position.

With this terminology in mind, in the type `[a] -> a`, I would certainly call `a` a type variable; I would object to calling `a` a type parameter; and I would be okay with calling `a` a type argument (since it is used in the type application `[] a` written in sugary style).

Note that even though in this case one might reasonably call `a` both a type variable and a type argument this does *not* mean that the two terms are synonymous! Saying that `a` is a type variable is pointing out that it has not yet been made concrete, whereas saying that `a` is a type argument is pointing out that it is being used to fill in a parameter of some other type -- which is emphasizing two very different things about `a` in that type!

Just to round out some the answer with some examples demonstrating the difference between the terms, consider these type declarations taken from the Prelude:

```
undefined :: a
(>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
not :: Bool -> Bool
otherwise :: Bool
```

The `a` in the type of `undefined` is a type variable but not a type argument; likewise the `m` in the type of `(>>=)` is a type variable but in most of the places it appears is not a type argument.

Both appearances of `Bool` in the type of `not` are type arguments but not type variables. (Just like the type `[t]` is sugar for `[] t`, the type `t1 -> t2` is sugar for `(->) t1 t2`.)

The `a` and `b` in the type of `(>>=)` are both type variables and type arguments.

The `Bool` in the type of `otherwise` is neither a type variable nor a type argument.

Comment: Since types are generally opposed to terms, perhaps "type-level language" or some such would be better.

Comment: Also, a *parameter* is often opposed to an *index*, so I'd use "argument" from both ends and historical terminology be damned. In fact, the whole parameter/argument nonsense seems to be mostly bad pedantry.

Comment: @dfeuer Not sure I'm on board with the "language" suggestion. A language is a collection of terms.

Comment: A language is a collection of words.